# Serenity-JS: ReferenceError: beforeAll is not defined

Tags: protractor, serenity-js

I'm trying to run my existing Protractor script using Serenity-JS.
In order to do so, I followed the internet's instructions and added the following to my config after installing Serenity-JS ('*npm install -g serenity-js*', plus the required '*npm install -g mocha --save-dev*');

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('serenity-js'),
    // ...
}
```

The framework is attempting to run my test but does not seem to recognize my beforeAll().
I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: beforeAll is not defined
```

My Protractor script which is referenced by my conf file contains the following code at the start:

```
var generic = require('./generic.js');
var tools = new generic.Tools();

describe('Testscript 1', function () {

    beforeAll( function () {
        //Open none angular site
        browser.driver.get('http://localhost/');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="url"]/option[4]')).click();
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="submit"]')).click();
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.refresh();
    });
```

I'm totally new to a framework around Protractor, so I have no idea where to look.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though on the surface [Mocha](https://mochajs.org) and [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/)'s syntax might look similar, they're in fact two completely different frameworks with slightly different semantics.

For example, while in Jasmine you'd use `beforeAll()`, in Mocha you have `before()`.

To make your test work with Mocha you need to make sure that you're using the [correct syntax](https://mochajs.org/#hooks):

```
describe('Testscript 1', function () {
    before( function () {
        //Open none angular site
        browser.driver.get('http://localhost/');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="url"]/option[4]')).click();
        browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="submit"]')).click();
    });

    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.refresh();
    });
```

Now regarding, the [Serenity/JS](http://serenity-js.org/) part :-)

You don't need to install `serenity-js`, `mocha` or `protractor` globally (the `-g` switch). In fact, in my view, that's an anti-pattern.

Have a look at the [Installation section](http://serenity-js.org/overview/installation.html) of the [Serenity/JS Handbook](http://serenity-js.org) to find out more about the dependencies you need.

I hope this [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)!

Best,

Jan

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks a lot for the help. Changing beforeAll to before helped fix the issue I mentioned in my post. I now have a different issue with my Protractor test, but that's something completely different. I can continue my struggle now! :)